# Vuejs socketio with router.push

Tags: socket.io, vuejs3

I make a game with socket io and vuejs only when I make a router.push it disconnects me from socket.io . I'd like to know where the problem comes from? it's because of the router.push?

**roomArea.vue**

```js
import {onMounted, onUnmounted, ref} from "vue";
import router from "@/router/index.js";
import socket from '@/socket';
let createorjoin = ref(true);
let roomName = ref('');
let inviteCode = ref('');
let username = ref('');
let privacy = ref(false);

function createRoom() {
if(roomName.value.length < 3) {
  alert('Le nom du salon doit contenir au moins 3 caractères');
} else {
  socket.emit('createRoom', roomName.value, privacy.value, 'zizi');

}
}

function joinRoom() {
if(inviteCode.value.length < 6) {
  alert('Le code d\'invitation doit contenir au moins 6 caractères');
  return;
} else {
  socket.emit('joinRoom', inviteCode.value, username.value);
}
}

onMounted(() => {
  socket.on('roomCreated', (room, code) => {
    router.push({name: 'Room', params: {id: code}});
  });
})
```

**socket.js**

```js
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

export default socket;
```

I've tested with something other than router.push and it works, but as soon as I use router.push it disconnects me directly from the server.